# Discrepancy between JasperServer and JasperSoft Studio xlsx export

Tags: jasper-reports

I have **crosstab report** designed with **Jaspersoft studio** which has some merged columns, everything is ok when I make a preview in xlsx but when I make an export on **Jasper Server** the **xlsx** file hasn't **merge any columns**.

Comment: In your case you had multiple row group entries and you needed the left ones span across multiple lines to accommodate the entries in the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The cells were not merging, and changing the attribute collapseRowSpan in applicationContext.xml on the server to false fixed it.

Here is the explanation http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/xls-export-parameters-jasperreports-server